# how to show hello world in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am using `react-native` using `ES6` try to show 'hello world' why it is not display hello world text ..

here is my code

https://rnplay.org/apps/zFnEdg

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(React.Text, {style: styles.text}, "Hello World!");
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinderApp', () => PropertyFinderApp);
```

Comment: have you created html file for this? e.g. helloworld.html?, if yes would you show me that

Comment: no i don't create helloworld.html

Comment: isn't it necessary, basically .html file will show the html code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eueenjrL/   does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not working because you are using **styles** and **styles** is not even defined.

Also you have to import React from **'react'** library and not from '**react-native'**, as you can see in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#render-a-movie)

Your code should look like this.

```
import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
});


class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<View>
           <Text style={styles.text}> "Hello World!"</Text>
         </View>)
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinderApp', () => PropertyFinderApp);
```

Here you got your example in rnplay, check the android version for example.

[rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/KGxX4A)

Comment: please fork your example

Comment: I am using 0.24 version

Comment: I added the example to the answer, seems like you have to import React from react-native in that emulator, don't do that in a real project anyway.

Comment: you forgot to import Component, use React.Component instead of just Component.

Comment: got it /..in some tutorial it extends with component ..and some case it extend with React.component ..which is correct

Comment: both ways are correct, it's just a different way to import it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112566/discussion-between-user944513-and-qop).